How can i make this scrollable div not have an offset from the left side of the screen?
How can make the "scroll" div not appear too far to the right?
Not exactly sure how to go about fixing this.
ScreenShot-1
ScreenShot-2


.scroll {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1500px;
  /* background-color:#CCC; */
  overflow-x: auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.img-fluid-1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: left; justify-content: left">
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="scroll d-flex flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 1" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 1</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 2" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 2</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 3" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 3</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 3.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 2" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 2</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 3" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 3</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




remove width: 1500px; from .scroll and add overflow-x-hidden class to .container Is that what are you looking for? or did I miss something?

It's the container class styling which is limiting the width and creating these spaces on the sides.

Either remove the container class from the div or remove the div entirely.


.scroll {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.img-fluid-1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: left; justify-content: left">
  <div class="mt-5">
    <div class="scroll d-flex flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 1" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 1</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 2" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 2</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 3" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 3</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 3.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 2" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 2</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 2.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 p-2">
        <img class="img-fluid-1" src="https://placehold.co/400x500" alt="Image 3" />
        <h5 class="mt-2">Image Title 3</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Description for image 3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




you are a genius! TY!

No prob, glad it helped. You can reward me by marking this answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.
